# MATLAB - reordering blocks of rows

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a 18x2 matrix where the rows are divided into blocks. Each block contains three rows, i.e. the matrix is made up of six blocks. The first column contains the block indices, which are in ascending order from 1 to 6. The second column contains the real data, which is 1 to 18 for illustrative puropeses. The matrix looks like this:

```
mat = [ ...
1, 1;
1, 2;
1, 3;
2, 4;
2, 5;
2, 6;
3, 7;
3, 8;
3, 9;
4, 10;
4, 11;
4, 12;
5, 13;
5, 14;
5, 15;
6, 16;
6, 17;
6, 18]
```

I also have a random vector comprising of six integer elements within the range 1 to 6, such as

```
perm = [2;4;1;2;4;6]
```

I now need to reorder the matrix according to the order of perm. The new matrix should look like this:

```
matNew = [ ...
2, 4;
2, 5;
2, 6;
4, 10;
4, 11;
4, 12;
1, 1;
1, 2;
1, 3;
2, 4;
2, 5;
2, 6;
4, 10;
4, 11;
4, 12;
6, 16;
6, 17;
6, 18]
```

I came up with a result by using a for-loop where I sequentially copied the individual blocks to matNew. However, the real matrix may be as big as 10,000 x 15 and I need to perform these permutation 1000 to 10000 times and save it in a 3D-array/struct/cell array, whatever is suited best in terms of performance.

Comment: No, the block length can be set by the user, i.e. it is not always 3. The second column can contain any floating number. I just put ascending integers for illustrative purpose.

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers if they solved your question. It's the check mark on the left side of the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This approach is fastest by a mile if you have different matrices each 
time, but takes approximately twice as long time as erfan's code if only `perm` changes.**

---

You can do this by creating a list of indices for each of the `perm` elements, using `bsxfun`. `n` is the number of elements per index. Then you use this to create the list you want:

```
perm_rep = bsxfun(@plus, n*(perm-1), 1:n).'
matNew = mat(perm_rep, :)

matNew =

     2     4
     2     5
     2     6
     4    10
     4    11
     4    12
     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     4
     2     5
     2     6
     4    10
     4    11
     4    12
     6    16
     6    17
     6    18
```

**Benchmarking:**

The following benchmarking is done with the following data:

```
sz_mat = size(mat)
num_perms = numel(perm)

sz_mat =    
       18000          20    
num_perms =    
        1000
```

The functions are adapted to fit in a function with varying matrix sizes, and timed using `timeit`. The approach above is about 200 times faster than erfan's approach, and 3 times faster than rahnema1's.

```
f = @() erfan(mat, perm);
g = @() stewie(mat, perm);
h = @() rahnema1(mat, perm);

isequal(f(), g(), h());

fprintf('Erfan: %f s\nStewie: %f s\nrahnema1: %f s\n',timeit(f), timeit(g), timeit(h));



Erfan: 0.003353 s
Stewie: 0.000139 s
rahnema1: 0.000620 s
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to apply many permutations (although it is not really a permutation), the fastest way is to separate each block and concatenate them according to `perm`:

```
% in RESHAPE: 3: # of rows per block, 2: # of columns
matblock = permute(reshape(mat.', 2, 3, []), [2, 3, 1]);
% perm = [2;4;1;2;4;6];
matNew = reshape(matblock(:,perm,:), [], 2, 1); % 2: same as above
```

**Another way** to do this looks simpler:

```
id = reshape(1:18, 3,[]);
matNew = mat(reshape(id(:, perm), [], 1),:);
```

Note that in both solutions the first command is executed once at the beginning, while the second one runs each time you update `perm`.

#### Benchmarking:

Since OP wants to apply several permutations to the same `mat`, I do the benchmarking in this way:

All the parts of the code that has nothing to do with `perm` is executed once. The parts that `perm` is involved are executed 100000 times for the provided `mat`:

```
------------------- With Erfan's first solution:
Elapsed time is 3.979285 seconds.
------------------- With Erfan's second solution:
Elapsed time is 4.245531 seconds.
------------------- With Stewie's solution:
Elapsed time is 6.998606 seconds.
------------------- With rahnema1's solution
Elapsed time is 8.278994 seconds.
```

*Update on benchmarking:*

I tried a different benchmarking, this time with a 10000 x 15 `mat`, with 10000 runs in this way:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% common code which runs once
mat = rand(10000, 15);
mat(:, 1) = reshape(repmat(1:2000, 5, 1), [], 1);
n = 5; % rows each block
perm = randi(2000, 6, 1);
spr = sparse(1:size(mat,1), mat(:,1),1:size(mat,1));
matblock = permute(reshape(mat.', 15, n, []), [2, 3, 1]);
id = reshape(1:10000, n, []);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

turn = 10000;

disp('------------------- With Erfan''s first solution:')
tic, for ii = 1:turn, Native; end, toc

disp('------------------- With Erfan''s second solution:')
tic, for ii = 1:turn, Native2; end, toc

disp('------------------- With Stewie''s solution:')
tic, for ii = 1:turn, Alter; end, toc

disp('------------------- With rahnema1''s solution:')
tic, for ii = 1:turn, Alter2; end, toc
```

And these are the scripts:

```
%%% Native
matNew1 = reshape(matblock(:,perm,:), [], 15, 1);

%%% Native2
matNew2 = mat(reshape(id(:, perm), [], 1),:);

%%% Alter
perm_rep = bsxfun(@plus, n*(perm-1), 1:n).';
matNew3 = mat(perm_rep, :);

%%% Alter2
matNew4 = mat(nonzeros(spr(:,perm)),:);
```

And here is the results of my benchmarking. Actually there is not much of difference seen here, unless one needs to continuously make this calculation. Otherwise it is just a matter of preference which code to use.

```
------------------- With Erfan's first solution:
Elapsed time is 0.502261 seconds.
------------------- With Erfan's second solution:
Elapsed time is 0.495179 seconds.
------------------- With Stewie's solution:
Elapsed time is 0.805442 seconds.
------------------- With rahnema1's solution:
Elapsed time is 0.529585 seconds.
```

Comment: I finally managed to properly write my benchmarking. Please check and let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Nice :) Note that it's better and much more accurate to use `timeit`. You can do it like this: `f = @() myfun(matblock, perm); timeit(f)`. Note that the scripts must be functions, and the input is given directly when creating `f`. The anonymous function can't take any input itself.

Comment: As far as I see it, your solutions are working properly. However, I have two issues that slow down the whole computation:
1. When you repeat the computation 10000 times, the 'perm' vector has to randomly changed every run.
2. I need to save all 10000 matrices for further processing. This costs some considerably mount of time, at least if you put it in a 3D array when running the for-loop.
So, what is the most efficient way to store the data? I think it doesn't matter in what format (3D, cell array, struct).

Comment: 1. To generate `perm`s you can use [`randi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) as I did. Of course you will need to put it in the loop. What we did was just benchmarking. 2. Depends on what you want to do with the result. [Take a look at this answer.](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7815#answer_10744)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sparse matrix to store indices of rows . then use perm to extract indices of desired elements . This method works with different block sizes:

```
mat = [ ...
1, 1;
1, 2;
1, 3;
2, 4;
2, 5;
2, 6;
3, 7;
3, 8;
3, 9;
4, 10;
4, 11;
4, 12;
5, 13;
5, 14;
5, 15;
6, 16;
6, 17;
6, 18];
perm = [2;4;1;2;4;6];
spr = sparse(1:size(mat,1), mat(:,1),1:size(mat,1));
out = mat(nonzeros(spr(:,perm)),:)
```